# I want to show that $\ker(h)=2\Bbb Z_2^2=2(\Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_2)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\Bbb Z_2$ be the ring of $2$-adic integers. I want to show $\Bbb Z_2^2/2\Bbb Z_2^2 \cong (\Bbb Z_2/2\Bbb Z_2)^2$.

**My approach:**

I think the Chinese Remainder Theorem doesn't help to factor the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_2^2/2\Bbb Z_2^2 $.

On the other hand, if I define the map $h:\Bbb Z_2^2=\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2 \to (\Bbb Z_2/2\Bbb Z_2)^2=\Bbb Z_2/2\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2/2\Bbb Z_2$ by $$ h(a,b)=(a+2 \Bbb Z_2, b+2\Bbb Z_2),$$ then it is a homomorphism.

I want to show that $\ker(h)=2\Bbb Z_2^2=2(\Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_2)$.

Now $2\Bbb Z_2^2=2(\Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_2)=\{2(u,v): (u,v) \in \Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_2 \}$. Then, \begin{align} h(2(u,v)) =(2u+2\Bbb Z_2, 2v+2\Bbb Z_2)&=(0+2\Bbb Z_2,0+2\Bbb Z_2) \\ &=\text{zero element in} \ \Bbb Z_2/2\Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_2/2\Bbb Z_2. \end{align}
If the above two lines are correct then we get the result.

Please help

Comment: You can show an equivalence $h(a,b)=(0,0)$ iff $a,b\in Z_2$ iff $(a,b)=(2s,2t),\,s,t\in Z_2$ iff $(a,b)=2(s,t)\in 2(Z_2\times Z_2)$.

Comment: Your two lines are correct but only show the inclusion $2\mathbb Z_2^2 \subseteq ker(h)$.

Comment: @PQH, Nice, but didn't  get why $h(a,b)=0$ iff $a,b \in Z_2$, the next parts are alright

Comment: $a+2Z_2=0+2Z_2$ iff $a\in 2Z_2.$ The same for $b$. I wrote $Z_2$ instead of $2Z_2$ above. My bad.